# Automatically purge rotated backup without breaking rsync

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, incremental-backup

How do I make sure locally deleted files have been rotated before deleting them on the server, whithout breaking incremental rsyncing?

I usually rsync my files into `/backup/active/` on my server, which should always contain the latest mirror, and should reflect what's on the client to 100%. This entire folder will be rotated nightly to `/backup/cold/` using `ddar` and online using [tarsnap](http://tarsnap.com). I want to make sure that every snapshot that is rotated contains only the files that were actually on the clients at the time. How can I make sure that files that are deleted on the client also gets deleted in the backup, without breaking rsync or accidentally deleting non-rotated files?

I don't want to use `rsync --remove` because that might remove files that haven't been rotated and backed up yet. Nor can I just shift the entire `/backup/` folder a rotation, because I need to keep rsync's incremental functions.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using rsync linking capabilities (`--link-dest`) to maintain a hierarchy of backups.

Comment: I want to keep things simple to avoid mistakes, and hard links are one of the things I'm not yet comfortable enough using that I want to risk my backups.

Answer (score 1):

So the objective is to secure the backups, right? I assume we don't care how it works as long as it gets the job done.

So, whilst Oliver gives the right hint `--link-dest` there is no reason to reinvent the wheel unless you want to learn and make your own experiences.

[rsnapshot](http://www.rsnapshot.org/screenshots.html) was invented for this purpose, has been used for several years now, and if you want the sourcecode, you may find it available [on github](https://github.com/DrHyde/rsnapshot).

For a quick story of other users experiences, try to read this blog: http://rayed.com/wordpress/?p=1379 as it gives a quick sense of "lessons learned".